# C# windows service is still running but non-responsive

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have c# window service created in server. Which has sqlite database. Client machine uses c# windows form application to connect to server and get data from server db. 
So as first thing client application login to server using http request. And server receives the request and send back the data to client.

But sometimes even if the service is running the server is not responsive to the client and client is not able to connect to server. Later i restart the service and then it connects.

```
System.Data.DataSet rdr = db.ExecuteDataSet(@"
                select i.id
                from item i,field f
                where i.typeid=1 and
                    f.value like '" + UserName + "' and i.id=f.itemid");

            if (rdr.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {

                rdr = null;
                return false;
            }



public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(String sqlExpr)
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                Open(DataFile);


                SQLiteDataAdapter _adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlExpr, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                _adapter.Fill(ds);

                return ds;

        }
```

Above is the code for login .Is there something blocking db. Please help me with your valuable answers.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: Have you traced the HTTP requests using a proxy like HTTP Fiddle? What did you do to determine that it's the DB query that takes a long time?

Comment: Are you catching & handling exceptions from your code?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have sure, but, if the loggin works well, the problem seems like have a error in the server, when you open the connection with de sqlite you close it after use?
the sqlite have some routine to kill connection in sleep?

Other thing, did you use the component.dispose()? because if you dont dispose the components, they keep use memory.